# When I try to iterate through a row of a dataframe in R and put the values in a vector, the values end up changing. What is causing that?

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, vector

I want to iterate through a dataframe in R and put each value in a separate numeric vector. As you can see, in the original dataframe (called singaporeINF, see the first photo), the values are all between 3000 and 4000.

[image: The dataframe I am trying to get the values from, singaporeINF]

However, when I iterate and extract the values using the code below:

```
singaporeVector <- numeric()
for (i in singaporeINF){
  singaporeVector <- append(singaporeVector, i)
}
print(singaporeVector)
```

I end up with this output:

```
[1] 10  8  8  8  8  8  7  8
```

What is happening? Why do the values change from 3000 to 10 or 8?

[image: Output]

Comment: I'm guessing your numbers are stored as factors. Try `append(singaporeVector, as.numeric(as.character(i)))` or `append(singaporeVector, as.numeric(gsub(" ", "", as.character(i))))`

Answer (score 1):

My response is better set up as a comment, but I lack the reputation to do that.

Check what `class()` those values are in the dataframe, it looks like there might be a space in them, which might mean those values are either a character or, more likely, a factor. Try

```
singaporeVector <- numeric()
for (i in singaporeINF){
singaporeVector <- append(as.numeric(as.character(singaporeINF)), i)
}
print(singaporeVector)
```

That said, if I'm right with the class issue, it would be easier to do the following without the loop:

```
singaporeVector <- as.numeric(as.character(singaporeINF[1,]))
```